# Motion Blur Isn't Applied on Object

Tags: eevee-render-engine, motion-blur

I'm trying to apply motion blur to a scene of moving hands.

The desired effect is:

[image]

I played around with the motion blur settings, setting the shutter to anywhere between 0.1 and 20, and the samples anywhere from 4 to 50, but no luck.

My scene settings: (Blender 2.8)

[image]

And here is the output:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKbNpQIOjc0

As you can see, around the 5th frame the right-hand starts swiping right in a total of 4 frames, but in all of them, it looks fine and not blurry like there is no movement.

I also tried removing the texture, did not seem to have an effect.

Comment: Motion blur is work only for camera motion in eevee. So try to sake the camera instead of the hand. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/motion_blur.html

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware and couldn't find anything regarding this. Probably searched wrong.